# How to hide a div/image on page load where it is looped in php array and with different id

Tags: javascript, php

I am listing some products from database, there is a div to reduce the product quantity from cart and its id is attached with the html id attribute. I want to hide this div on page load. What is best solution for it

```
<img src="images/add-minus.png" class="minus-image" onClick="removeitem('<?php echo $row12['itemid'];?>')" id="minus-image<?php echo $row12['itemid'];?>">
```

I need to hide this div on page load

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="display:none"`;

For example how to using it and how to display if you need it.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#view", function(){
  $('#test').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="test" style="display:none">Lorem Ipsum</p>

<button id='view' class='pull-left' title='Save'>Show Content</button>
```